# I install Ubuntu 13.10 and reboot and im on KDE desktop?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kde, ubuntu-unity

Hi I'm Jacob and I have no idea what's going on. I installed Ubuntu 13.10 today and was playing around with it for a while and dl'd a bunch of apps from software center and stuff. Eventually I installed steam and (finally) got it working. I downloaded TF2 and had some weird issue where the screen got so distorted to the point I could not play. So I dl'd a driver for my graphics card from the additional drivers app (or whatever it's called) and when it was done I restarted my computer (because it said to.) When the PC booted up it loaded the KDE desktop and I have no idea why. I had unity before I rebooted. Ubuntu 13.10 is the only OS installed on my PC, and I still have all the apps that I downloaded, but I kinda like unity (I started using Ubuntu after they switched to unity) and want it back.

Thanks for reading and any help in advance, Jacob.

Comment: Can you give us the output of " echo $DESKTOP_SESSION"?

Answer (score 0):

When you get to the login screen, choose another desktop (in your case ubuntu) by clicking on the small gear.